# why my syntax highlighing for vue3 is not working?

Tags: vuejs3, syntax-highlighting

recently i started to learn vue3 with the Composition API.
I´d installed Vetur and Volar but i get a crappy code highlighting and sometimes the code is not working.

Anyone know a fix for that?

[image: Here my example]

This code works 100%.
That can not be it

Comment: Do not use Vetur with Vue 3.  Just use Volar